# Can I reuse a bottle that had a sour lactobacillus beer in it?

Tags: sanitation, cleaning, sour, bottle, lactobacillus

I had a very nice sour beer that had lactobacillus in it and was wondering if I can clean and reuse the bottle?

I have not made any sour beers yet but I've read you should keep separate brewing equipment when making them because even the most conscientious cleaner and sanitiser can't be confident of killing it all.

Can I reuse the bottle for beer that doesn't contain lactobacillus? I have a dishwasher if that helps? Would the steam cycle kill it all?

Comment: Glass or plastic bottles?  Because plastic can't be cleaned/sanitized by heat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bacteria like to hang out in soft surfaces like rubber and plastic, which for us usually includes things like buckets, hoses, and o-rings.  Also any metal fittings for your valves, etc.

Glass bottles have none of these problems.  You can safely clean and sanitize your bottles and reuse them for any kind of beer.  If you are very concerned, the best way to sterilize them is to bake in an oven at about 175 F for about 5 minutes, then just turn the oven off and let them cool inside the oven slowly for a couple of hours.  That will kill everything guaranteed.